# How to disable the keyring for SSH and GPG?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, keyrings

How to disable the keyring for SSH and GPG ?

I would like to keep the keyring for the wifi and other stuff. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can't you simply decline to save those passwords on the keyring?  For standard ssh, it won't save the password unless you set it up that way specifically, in my experience.

Comment: I don't know. Is there a way to reset the keyring. To test it? The title in the topic had Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in it, but @jorge-castro changed it.

Comment: Keyring hasn't changed much in a while, but I added it to the question for clarity, no need for it to clutter the title though as the answer will likely apply to multiple versions.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what is your motivation for disabling keyring for SSH ?

Comment: @Stephane I cant speak for OP but I do not want an information so critical exposed in any way. I would rather input my ssh key password every time I am connecting to some server, than the keyring storing it, allowing any program and every person in my user space arbitrary ssh access. This doesnt make sense for everyone else, of course, but imo the motivation here is understandable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First duplicate the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` into `~/.config/autostart/`.

Then edit `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` in order to remove the following line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

and to add the following line at the end:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

This should disable SSH management when you restart your session.
To disable GPG, do the same with the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop`.

Comment: Tnx, this finally solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

In a terminal session (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) you can stop the gnome-keyring process from working with ssh by using:

```
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

The `--no-use-agent` option is available to gpg to avoid using the gnome-keyring process with gpg, however that is the default.

You can stop the nautilus seahorse-tool from using the gpg-agent by using:

```
rm `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO | sed s/:0:1//`
```

You can stop the gnome-keyring process completely with the command:

```
kill $GNOME_KEYRING_PID
```

Each of the above actions is restored by logging in again.

---

Wifi passwords *available to all userids* are stored in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory rather than being stored in your gnome keyring, so they can remain available if you kill the gnome-keyring process.

The `ssh-add` command can be used to delete (or add) specific keys from/to the current gnome-keyring while the keyring process is running.

Individual key passwords can be deleted from the login or other keyring using the `Passwords` tab of the `Passwords and Keys` program (seahorse).

If the gnome-keyring isn't present, ssh-agent will still be running, but it doesn't store gpg keys.

---

There are two lines in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` involved with saving the login password and starting the gnome-keyring-daemon with the login keyring unlocked with the login password. The second starts the daemon:

```
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

Commenting out just this line would stop it from starting for all sessions of all users of your system using the login password to unlock the login keyring.

`/etc/xdg/autostart/` contains start entries for various categories of secrets gnome-keyring can handle. To stop the daemon from starting these components these files can be moved out of this directory. You can move all the gnome-keyring-* files to stop the daemon from starting or can simply refuse to supply the login password again to disable the login keyring while leaving the daemon running.

Comment: unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK works. Tnx. Is there a way to unset it for all sessions? I use Enigmail for Thunderbird and there is a problem with enigmail (it doesn't forget the password).

Comment: Is there a way to disable the keyring at startup. (I really don't want to write a script killing the keyring).

Comment: I've edited the answer with some more information that may be helpful, however it may be better to ask for an Enigmail circumvention directly in a separate question, being explicit about what you want.

Comment: You can flush the keyring (forget your passwords, both gpg and ssh and others) by doing `gnome-keyring-daemon -r -d`. This is simple way of restarting the daemon. One possible problem is that if it wasn't running in the first place, it'll start up (I don't know a good way of only restarting it if it's already running, except parsing `ps` :/)

Answer (score 2):

To stop gnome-keyring from starting its ([broken](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549413)) SSH agent on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
mkdir ~/.config/upstart || true
echo manual > ~/.config/upstart/gnome-keyring-ssh.override

# This step can be done with the gnome-session-properties tool
mkdir ~/.config/autostart || true
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ~/.config/autostart
echo 'X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false' >> ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
```

Comment: I see that your last line is utilizing the fact that /usr/share/upstart/sessions/gnome-keyring-ssh.conf looks for that line and exits immediately before exporting the SSH_AUTH_SOCK, I think that you don't need the ~/.config/upstart file/directory if you also append `Hidden=true` to the .desktop file. This basically masks the "real" (system) shortcut from all desktops, even those it might normally apply to like GNOME/Unity. I'll be testing this shortly as I've been looking for a clean way to disable gnome-keyring-ssh without affecting the other functions.

Answer (score 1):

With current version of Ubuntu, changing the `.desktop` file mentioned in other answers is not sufficient anymore. An additional upstart job [was added](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1271591) that also starts `gnome-keyring-daemon`. The file is located in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/gnome-keyring.conf` and contains:

```
eval "$(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)" >/dev/null
initctl set-env --global SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
initctl set-env --global GPG_AGENT_INFO=$GPG_AGENT_INFO
```

Here the daemon needs to be restricted to only provide some services by adding `--components=pkcs11,secrets` to the command line. The `initctl` lines can also be removed, resulting in:

```
eval "$(gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets)" >/dev/null
```

Comment: How can I override this file per user without modifying the system file?

Comment: Changing a system file is a bad practice. See my own answer.