# 14.04 Disable keyring for SSH and GPG

Tags: 14.04, ssh, keyrings

Up until recently the following solution worked well:

[How to disable the keyring for SSH and GPG?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162850/how-to-disable-the-keyring-for-ssh-and-gpg)

But just a few days ago the solution stopped working for SSH. I now get a GUI prompt for my SSH password and it keeps the key unlocked until I close the terminal session.

I had read some suggestions regarding changing the permissions for the keyring executable so that it can't be executed, and while that works, I won't get a password prompt for wifi networks :P So I opted to reverse that.

Is there anything I can be doing to tackle this particular issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and have only just taken the time to fix it.

I fully documented this in my install procedure here:

https://github.com/mattcaron/misc_notes/blob/master/install.xubuntu.14.04

See item 36.

However, the crux of it is twofold:

1. You need to have the default `gnome-keyring-daemon` not start all the components, so I create a wrapper such that `gnome-keyring-daemon` is now `gnome-keyring-daemon-wrapped`, and the new `gnome-keyring-daemon` does:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon-wrapped --components=pkcs11,secrets,gpg "$@
   ```
2. You also need to edit `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` and add the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
   ```

After that, it seems to behave itself properly.

Comment: It seems that adding the line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to the file `~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop` is sufficient for me.