# gpg ask for passphrase every time although gpg-agent is configured

Tags: kde, gnupg

On Kubuntu Trusty and before, I had the GnuPG agent set up such that it would only ask for the password occasionally, like this:

I have a `.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
utf8-strings
keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve
default-key 68B8AA90
keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net
use-agent
encrypt-to 68B8AA90
```

And a `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt4
default-cache-ttl 3600
max-cache-ttl 3600
```

Now after upgrading to Kubuntu Utopic, it asks for the password every single time! The password dialog looks different though, so I suggest that `pinentry-qt4` is not started at all.

How can I get it to remember my passphrase?

Comment: This is probably the Gnome Keyring interfering. If so, [use dconf to configure caching](http://askubuntu.com/a/358514/167385).

Comment: I use KDE and Awesome WM. I would prefer not to use the Gnome Keyring. I updated the question.

Comment: Have a look at the running processes and see if my guess was right. Or if it is installed at all. I'm not sure whether KDE brings its own keyring acting as `gpg-agent`. Did you try running `/usr/bin/pinentry-qt4` manually?

Comment: I just did `ps -e | grep gnome` and found `2118 ?        00:00:01 gnome-keyring-d`. So you are right. Now that I think about it, the dialog looks like Gnome. How can I deactivate this then and replace by a KDE component? Does NetworkManager depend on this to store the WLAN passwords?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. But what about starting Gnome Keyring and having a look what's stored in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the keyring for SSH and GPG?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162850/how-to-disable-the-keyring-for-ssh-and-gpg)