# Disable gnome from asking passphrase in GUI when using ssh and gpg from terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, ssh, 16.10, gnupg

Ever since I installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.10 Gnome(previously I had 15.10), I have been annoyed with the fact that whenever I try to add an SSH key or import a GPG key using terminal a GUI popup box pops up asking for the passphrase.

With SSH, I work around this issue by starting a new agent on the terminal and then trying to add the key. And finally, it asks me for the passphrase in TTY or not a GUI.

With GPG I just started learning it, so not sure how to workaround.

Is there a way I can disable this and make them ask for the passphrase in TTY when accessed from TTY?

I have read the answers in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162850) question and but it is about ubuntu 12.04 and the top two answers didn't work for me.

Comment: What about the last answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/806006/158442

Comment: @guntbert: OP doesn't want to disable the SSH and/or GPG agent(s). He wants the password dialogue to appear on the terminal instead of in a new X window when the application requesting SSH/GPG key access is running insidea terminal application.

Comment: See [How to force GPG to use console-mode pinentry to prompt for passwords?](//superuser.com/q/520980/238583)

Comment: For a simple gpg decript command use `gpg --pinentry-mode loopback -d criptedfile.txt.gpg -o file.txt` and it will ask passphrase in the command line. No need to reconfigure.

Comment: So, what you're asking is, "How do I disable the GUI prompts and only make it ask in the shell/TTY directly without using any GUI agents?

Answer (score 18):

SSH and GPG use so-called "agents" to cache decrypted private keys, so that users don't have to enter their pass phrases all the time. By default they use the program `pinentry` to this purpose.

Before we continue let's make sure that an example for a command-line pin entry program is available on your system. In Ubuntu's repository we have `pinentry-curses` (since forever) and `pinentry-tty` (since Xenial) but they're not installed by default. You can get it from the package of the same name:

```
sudo apt install pinentry-curses
```

### Setting a different pin entry program

You can adjust the program used for pin entry by either:

- (per-user) Setting `pinentry-program` in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` to a command-line pin entry program, e. g.:

  ```
  pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
  ```

  You need to either restart the agent or have it reload its configuration:

  ```
  gpg-connect-agent <<< RELOADAGENT
  ```
- (system-wide) In all common Linux distributions including Ubuntu the default `pinentry` program is actually a symbolic link to the actual pin entry program. The target of this symbolic link is managed by the `update-alternatives` system. You can use it to change the link target to a command-line pin entry program:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry
  ```

### Choosing the pin entry program based on the availability of a terminal

The disadvantage of both of these methods is that you won't be able to use a command-line pin entry if SSH or GPG are invoked from a program running without a terminal, e. g. a graphical SFTP client or a mail user agent. A better way would be to use the graphical pin entry program only when an X server is available and a terminal is *un*available. To this purpose we'll need a small wrapper script that analyses the environment before deferring to the right pin entry program.

Let's assume we have the following executable shell script at `~/.local/bin/my-smart-pinentry`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

# Configuration -- adjust these to your liking
PINENTRY_TERMINAL='/usr/bin/pinentry-curses'
PINENTRY_X11='/usr/bin/pinentry-x11'

# Action happens below!
if [ -n "${DISPLAY-}" -a -z "${TERM-}" ]; then
    exec "$PINENTRY_X11" "$@"
else
    exec "$PINENTRY_TERMINAL" "$@"
fi
```

To use this wrapper as the pin entry "program" you can use the per-user method mentioned above. You can also [add it to the `update-alternatives` database](/a/410070/175814).

Answer (score 2):

If anyone will find this question while using newer version like I do then there is much simpler solution. At least the one which works for me with GPG v2.2.19 in (K)ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal. All I had to add was just `--pinentry-mode loopback` and it started to ask for a password in TTY. I didn't have to install anything. For example:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --export-secret-keys -a | less
```